# Resizing image regarding browser window without distortion

Tags: jquery, browser, resize, window, autoresize

I have an img tag, I want to re-size it regarding the browser window, without distortion.

the img takes a (width: 100%), so its height will be greater than browser window.
and when the image height be <= browser window, it will stop resizing, else it will re-size.

so; it didn't works !!

here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>testawy</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
body
{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
<body>
<img id="str" src="stretch.jpg">
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    $("#str").width($(window).width());
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    var x = $(window).height();
    var y = $("#str").height();

    if (y <= x)
    {
        $("#str").height('500px');
    }
    else
    {
        $("#str").width($(window).width());
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And the question is? Also, place that resize function inside the DOM ready function aswell.

Comment: It didn't re-size at all

Comment: Try : `$("#str").height(500);` instead ?

Comment: it didn't worked @adeneo

Comment: You do realize that if the window is taller then or equals the height of the image, the image will be set to a height of 500px, and there's nothing bringing it back to the original size, so it will only work once, and if the image is taller than the window, the image width will be the same as the window? It does seem rather strange?

Comment: @adeneo The Op's logic is definitely odd..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time ago, I needed this for a project and **I found a lot of resources about the subject here at SO** (almost sure this is a duplicated question), but here we go:

#### HTML

```
<img src="images/bg.jpg" id="bg" alt="">
```

#### Jquery

```
$(window).load(function() {    

    var theWindow        = $(window),
        $bg              = $("#bg"),
        aspectRatio      = $bg.width() / $bg.height();

    function resizeBg() {

        if ( (theWindow.width() / theWindow.height()) < aspectRatio ) {
            $bg
                .removeClass()
                .addClass('bgheight');
        } else {
            $bg
                .removeClass()
                .addClass('bgwidth');
        }

    }

    theWindow.resize(resizeBg).trigger("resize");
});
```

#### CSS:

```
#bg { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; }
.bgwidth { width: 100%; }
.bgheight { height: 100%; }
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/7Qcfy/3/

*Edit:* You was right, my code had few issues, this is the definitive answer... just what you are looking for :D

Comment: but when the image height be <= browser window, it didn't stop resizing. i want it to stop.

Comment: yes, you're right! but you have the variables, is just 2 lines, so... homework ;)

Comment: :( .. actually I have a lot :D

Comment: @SPrince:I noted few issues on my code, **check update** and [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Qcfy/3/)

Comment: You're welcome. If you want to learn more about check this awsome [tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is all you need...pretty much just check if the browser window is less than 500px.

```
function resizeIt() {

    var x = $(window).height();

    if ( x <= 500 ) {
        $("#str").attr('height', '500px').removeAttr('width');
    } else {
        $("#str").attr('width', '100%').removeAttr('height');
    }

}

resizeIt();


$(window).on('resize', resizeIt);
```